# having HMENU handle is it possible to run programatically an item from that menu?

Tags: winapi, menu, window

I have a HMENU and I know that the item lies at given position, having that information is it possible to do something like this: `RunMenuItem(hMenu,3)` where 3 is the position of that item ?

Comment: The real question is, "Where did you get that `HMENU` from? Perhaps the place you got it from exposes a better interface for executing commands. (E.g. automation.)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you select an item from a menu, one of two things can happen:

- A `WM_COMMAND` message is posted to the menu's parent window, containing the menu item ID, or
- If the menu was displayed with `TrackPopupMenu` **with** the `TPM_RETURNCMD` flag, the selected item ID is returned as the result of the call to `TrackPopupMenu`.

In the first case, you can simulate this programmatically by simply posting the `WM_COMMAND` message yourself with the appropriate parameters. You would need to query the `HMENU` for the menu item ID (using `GetMenuItemInfo`).

In the second case, there's no easy way to simulate this, as it relies on the calling thread actually calling `TrackPopupMenu` and processing the result.